# Select() method not found in BindingList<T>, System.Linq is included

Tags: c#, linq, bindinglist

I have the following [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) derived class.

```
class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T> where T: class
{
  public T GetRecord(T obj)
   {
      return base.Where(t => t.Equals(obj)) //Where and Select not found on base :(
             .Select(t => t).FirstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

Compiler is giving me the following error

> error CS0117: 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Where'

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way in which you're calling the extension method. You just need to use `this` instead of `base`. Calling extension methods on `this` is relatively unusual, but does need the `this` explicitly... and it can't be `base`, which suggests you're trying to call a method declared in one of the ancestors in the type hierarchy. A method invocation using `base` does not go through extension method invocation checks. From the C# 5 spec, section 7.6.5.2:

> In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of one of the forms
>
> ```
> expr . identifier ( )
> expr . identifier ( args )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
> ```
>
> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation.

That's not the case in your code. (`base` isn't an expression in itself. Having said that, I believe section 7.6.8 of the C# spec is inconsistent with this. I'll raise that with the C# team.)

This compiles fine:

```
public T GetRecord(T obj)
{
    return this.Where(t => t.Equals(obj))
               .Select(t => t).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

(I added a return type to the method - *please* take more care when asking questions in future, given the number of mistakes it seems you had in this one.)

Comment: That fixed the problem. Why base wont have it ?

Comment: Though that makes it compile, can you explain, WHY it makes a difference? As BindingList<T> implements IEnumerable<T>, therefore it should be possible to use the Where extension method on it.

Comment: @okrumnow: See my edit, which quotes the relevant part of the spec.

Comment: I think there is some rule limiting `base` from incorrect use, even we try this `Enumerable.Where<T>(base, ...)` -> error: `base is not valid in this context`

Comment: @KingKing: Well that's just a matter of `base` not being an expression in itself. It's only used for a base-access expression (section 7.6.8) or for constructor chaining.

Answer (score 3):

Select accepts a `Func<TSource, TResult>`, but you're passing `t`, which is an undeclared symbol... it should be

```
Select(t => t)
```

Also, you should use `this` instead of `base`.

Anyway, the call to `Select` is useless, since you're not actually transforming the input. You can also merge the `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` into a single call.

```
   public T GetRecord(T obj)
   {
      return this.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Equals(obj));
   }
```

Comment: My question had errors, I fixed those. I am still getting the compiler error. If you like I can share the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Try cast your instances from list

```
return base.Cast<T>().Where(t => t.Equals(obj)).Select(t).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: error CS0117 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Comment: You should add using System.Linq; to your using section